# What's the name of a right shift operator between closures in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I've found a groovy code snippet similar to the next one:

```
def f1 = { print "Hello, ${it}" }

def f2 = { "world" }​​​​​​​​

(f2 >> f1)()
```

It looks like such construction works only between closures. This code also works with left shift operator (`(f1 << f2)()`).

I wonder how is this operator (or this technique) called?

Comment: They're both at the same precedence, so you'd better remember the left-associativity rules when using them both together. I believe f1 << f2 >> f3 will associate like so: (f1 << f2) >> f3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does closure composition.

See the `rightShift` and `leftShift` [operator overloading API docs](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_operator_overloading).

Overriding shift operators is a pretty common technique, like for adding items to a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice list of all operators with their names [from the official documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_operator_overloading) which displays the names of <<, >>, >>=, .., ..<, <<=, >>= and so on. Whenever I stumble upon something in Groovy I don't know the name of, this is the place to go (see also the paragraph on [operator precedence](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_operator_precedence) on the same side).